# Error starting Windows docker container with managed service account

Tags: docker, active-directory, containers

I'm trying to test out docker containers running with a domain credential and I'm following [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/manage-serviceaccounts) from Microsoft Docs. I have created the Group MSA, which I'm pretty sure I've done correctly as I can run other services on my local computer using it.

I'm testing on a Windows 10 PC, running hyper-v docker containers.

I have built an image called `sqltest`. When I run the following, the container does evey as expected:

```
docker run -it sqltest
```

I tried creating active directory credentials using this command:

```
New-CredentialSpec -Name developerpcsql -AccountName developerpcsql
```

Calling `Get-CredentialSpec` confirms that the json file is created as expected, and it looks right when I open the file.

To run the container, I'm using:

```
docker run -it --security-opt "credentialspec=file://developerpcsql.json" sqltest
```

When I do that, it takes about 30 seconds and then I get the following error:

> Error response from daemon: container d97082fab98c0205c0072b0a8b79fb7835c8e90828498428b976e378762cc412 encountered an error during Start: failure in a Windows system call: The operation timed out  because a response was not received from the Virtual Machine hosting the Container. (0xc0370109).

To confirm it's not my container I've also tried using the standard microsoft/servercore container and get the same error.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: nope. still looking

Comment: Are you using Windows Containers and not the older underlying Linux VM?

Comment: Windows containers. The container runs fine without the credentialspec.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Did you find anything?  Containers run fine without the credentialspec.

Comment: still can't get it to work. Mine also works fine without credentialspec

Comment: I'm wondering if it's a Windows 10 issue. A few other people are reporting that it works on Server 2016, but not Windows 10

Comment: Having the same problem on Windows 10. Any updates you can share?

Comment: I haven't tried it again recently, been working on other thing, but I'm pretty sure it's a Windows 10 problem and it would work on Server 2016

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it does not work for Windows 10.
Here you can find discussion on the topic

[Virtualization-Documentation git repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/587)

It **does** work as expected for Windows Server 2016 Hosted container.